# Multiple subtables spanning both columns in a journal environment (double column)

Tags: tables, apa6, journal

I am trying to organize a set of regression results that I imported from Stata in my LaTeX document (MiKTeX) which is in a journal (apa6) environment.

I have three tables, and I would like to draw them in a single page spanning both columns in my double column text document type.

The desired format would be like this:

Table 1: First stage Results: Probability of Treatment

Table 1a: Vecinity +/-2
Table 1b: Vecinity +/-3
Table 1c: Vecinity +/-5

How can I merge these three tables making them subtables, and put them in a single page in my two column journal environment?

Thank you in advance for your feedback!

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}
%Packages    
\usepackage[american]{babel}    
\usepackage{hyperref}     
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}    
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}    
\usepackage{bookmark}    
\usepackage{apacite}    

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Results}

\begin{table*}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{First stage Results: Probability of Treatment (Vecinity +/-2)\label{regFS2.tex}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\hline\hline
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\hline
Eligibility Status (Z)&     0.14\sym{***}&     0.14\sym{***}&     0.10\sym{*}  &     0.10\sym{*}  \\
                &   (0.05)         &   (0.05)         &   (0.06)         &   (0.06)         \\
[1em]
SRII Index      &     0.01         &     0.21         &     0.00         &    -0.20         \\
                &   (0.02)         &   (0.75)         &   (0.02)         &   (0.81)         \\
[1em]
SRII 2          &                  &    -0.30         &                  &     0.30         \\
                &                  &   (1.11)         &                  &   (1.21)         \\
[1em]
Controls        &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
\hline
Observations    &     6925         &     6925         &     2291         &     2291         \\
R-squared       &     0.02         &     0.02         &     0.11         &     0.11         \\
F-statistic     &    10.07         &     6.72         &    12.59         &    11.68         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors are clustered at the household level.}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Significance levels: * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01.}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table*}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{First stage Results: Probability of Treatment (Vecinity +/-3)\label{regFS3.tex}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\hline\hline
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\hline
Eligibility Status (Z)&     0.12\sym{***}&     0.12\sym{***}&     0.12\sym{***}&     0.12\sym{**} \\
                &   (0.04)         &   (0.04)         &   (0.05)         &   (0.05)         \\
[1em]
SRII Index      &    -0.00         &    -0.13         &     0.01         &    -0.13         \\
                &   (0.01)         &   (0.27)         &   (0.01)         &   (0.29)         \\
[1em]
SRII 2          &                  &     0.20         &                  &     0.21         \\
                &                  &   (0.40)         &                  &   (0.43)         \\
[1em]
Controls        &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
\hline
Observations    &    10446         &    10446         &     3442         &     3442         \\
R-squared       &     0.02         &     0.02         &     0.10         &     0.10         \\
F-statistic     &    15.53         &    10.41         &    17.35         &    16.05         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors are clustered at the household level.}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Significance levels: * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01.}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table*}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{First stage Results: Probability of Treatment (Vecinity +/-5)\label{regFS5.tex}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\hline\hline
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\hline
Eligibility Status (Z)&     0.07\sym{**} &     0.07\sym{**} &     0.05         &     0.05         \\
                &   (0.03)         &   (0.03)         &   (0.04)         &   (0.04)         \\
[1em]
SRII Index      &    -0.02\sym{***}&     0.00         &    -0.02\sym{**} &     0.02         \\
                &   (0.01)         &   (0.08)         &   (0.01)         &   (0.08)         \\
[1em]
SRII 2          &                  &    -0.03         &                  &    -0.06         \\
                &                  &   (0.11)         &                  &   (0.12)         \\
[1em]
Controls        &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
\hline
Observations    &    17068         &    17068         &     5583         &     5583         \\
R-squared       &     0.03         &     0.03         &     0.11         &     0.11         \\
F-statistic     &    48.41         &    32.70         &    30.31         &    28.11         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors are clustered at the household level.}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Significance levels: * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01.}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\section{Conclusion}



\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{Bibliography_test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How exactly sould the tables be arranged? Do you want to show them one below the other or side by side? Please clarify.

Comment: Personally, I would combine all three tables into a single table thus avoiding to repeat the first column. Would that be ok for you as well?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems that OP is not active anymore and consequently (s)he will not accept any of received answers.

Comment: @Zarko -- I'm voting to reopen.  There are two reasonable answers, one of which is followed by a comment by the OP that it's workable.  It would be a shame to lose these answers.  (Tables can be beastly!)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a first rough version of how you could combine all three tables into one:

[image]

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}
%Packages    
\usepackage[american]{babel}    
\usepackage{hyperref}     
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}    
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}    
\usepackage{bookmark}    
\usepackage{apacite}  


\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} 

\begin{document}


\section{Results}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{First stage Results: Probability of Treatment\label{regFS2.tex}}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{12}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Vecinity +/-2} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Vecinity +/-3} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Vecinity +/-5}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
                      &\mc{(1)}      &\mc{(2)}          &\mc{(3)}         &\mc{(4)}          &\mc{(1)}      &\mc{(2)}          &\mc{(3)}         &\mc{(4)}        &\mc{(1)}      &\mc{(2)}          &\mc{(3)}         &\mc{(4)}         \\
\midrule
Eligibility Status (Z)& 0.14\sym{***}&     0.14\sym{***}&     0.10\sym{*} &     0.10\sym{*}  &     0.12\sym{***}&     0.12\sym{***}&     0.12\sym{***}&     0.12\sym{**} &     0.07\sym{**} &     0.07\sym{**} &     0.05         &     0.05         \\
                      & (0.05)       &   (0.05)         &   (0.06)        &   (0.06)         &   (0.04)         &   (0.04)         &   (0.05)         &   (0.05)         &   (0.03)         &   (0.03)         &   (0.04)         &   (0.04)         \\
\addlinespace
SRII Index            &   0.01       &     0.21         &     0.00        &    -0.20         &    -0.00         &    -0.13         &     0.01         &    -0.13         &    -0.02\sym{***}&     0.00         &    -0.02\sym{**} &     0.02         \\
                      & (0.02)       &   (0.75)         &   (0.02)        &   (0.81)         &   (0.01)         &   (0.27)         &   (0.01)         &   (0.29)         &   (0.01)         &   (0.08)         &   (0.01)         &   (0.08)         \\
\addlinespace
SRII 2                &              &    -0.30         &                 &     0.30         &                  &     0.20         &                  &     0.21         &                  &    -0.03         &                  &    -0.06         \\
                      &              &   (1.11)         &                 &   (1.21)         &                  &   (0.40)         &                  &   (0.43)         &                  &   (0.11)         &                  &   (0.12)         \\
\addlinespace
Controls              &     No       &       No         &      Yes        &      Yes         &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
\midrule
Observations          &   6925       &     6925         &     2291        &     2291         &    10446         &    10446         &     3442         &     3442         &    17068         &    17068         &     5583         &     5583         \\
R-squared             &   0.02       &     0.02         &     0.11        &     0.11         &     0.02         &     0.02         &     0.10         &     0.10         &     0.03         &     0.03         &     0.11         &     0.11         \\
F-statistic           &  10.07       &     6.72         &    12.59        &    11.68         &    15.53         &    10.41         &    17.35         &    16.05         &    48.41         &    32.70         &    30.31         &    28.11         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors are clustered at the household level.}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Significance levels: * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01.}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear Leandriis! It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

In preamble

- replace `\usepackage{threeparttable}` with `\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}` and use it in table design,
- add `tabularx` (for table environment)and `siunitx` package (for use of `S` column type which enable align of numbers at their decimal points)
- add definition for abbreviation for `multicolumn` commands, using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`  command (defined in `xparse` package, now is part of LaTeX kernel)

For table is used: font size `\small`, reduced `tabcolsep` to 2pt and customize `S` column parameters by `\sisetup`.

Considering above, your code can be rewritten as:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}
%Packages
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} % <--- for \note, \source
%\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Results}

    \begin{table*}[htbp]
    \centering
\sisetup{input-symbols=( ),
         table-format=-1.2,
         table-space-text-post=\tnote{***},
         group-four-digits}
    \small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{First stage Results: Probability of Treatment}
\label{regFS2.tex}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X *{12}{S} @{}}
    \toprule
    & \mc[4]{Vecinity +/-2} 
                    & \mc[4]{Vecinity +/-3} 
                                    & \mc[4]{Vecinity +/-5}\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-5} 
    \cmidrule(lr){6-9} 
    \cmidrule(l){10-13}
    &\mc{(1)}       &\mc{(2)}       &\mc{(3)}       &\mc{(4)}          
    &\mc{(1)}       &\mc{(2)}       &\mc{(3)}       &\mc{(4)}        
    &\mc{(1)}       &\mc{(2)}       &\mc{(3)}       &\mc{(4)}   \\
    \midrule
Eligibility Status (Z)
    & 0.14\tnote{***} & 0.14\tnote{***} & 0.10\tnote{*}   & 0.10\tnote{*}
    & 0.12\tnote{***} & 0.12\tnote{***} & 0.12\tnote{***} & 0.12\tnote{**}
    & 0.07\tnote{**}  & 0.07\tnote{**}  & 0.05          & 0.05      \\
    & (0.05)        & (0.05)        & (0.06)        & (0.06)
    & (0.04)        & (0.04)        & (0.05)        & (0.05)
    & (0.03)        & (0.03)        & (0.04)        & (0.04)    \\
    \addlinespace
SRII Index
    & 0.01          & 0.21          & 0.00          & -0.20
    & -0.00         & -0.13         & 0.01          & -0.13
    & -0.02\tnote{***}& 0.00          & -0.02\tnote{**} & 0.02      \\
    & (0.02)        & (0.75)        & (0.02)        & (0.81)
    & (0.01)        & (0.27)        & (0.01)        & (0.29)
    & (0.01)        & (0.08)        & (0.01)        & (0.08)    \\
    \addlinespace
SRII 2
    &               & -0.30         &               & 0.30
    &               & 0.20          &               & 0.21
    &               & -0.03         &               & -0.06     \\
    &               & (1.11)        &               & (1.21)
    &               & (0.40)        &               & (0.43)
    &               & (0.11)        &               & (0.12)    \\
    \addlinespace
Controls
    & {No}          & {No}          & {Yes}         & {Yes}
    & {No}          & {No}          & {Yes}         & {Yes}
    & {No}          & {No}          & {Yes}         & {Yes}     \\
    \midrule
Observations
    & \num{6925}    & \num{6925}    & \num{2291}    & \num{2291}
    & \num{10446}   & \num{10446}   & \num{3442}    & \num{3442}
    & \num{17068}   & \num{17068}   & \num{5583}    & \num{5583}\\
R-squared
    & 0.02          & 0.02          & 0.11          & 0.11
    & 0.02          & 0.02          & 0.10          & 0.10
    & 0.03          & 0.03          & 0.11          & 0.11      \\
F-statistic
    & 10.07         & 6.72          & 12.59         & 11.68
    & 15.53         & 10.41         & 17.35         & 16.05
    & 48.41         & 32.70         & 30.31         & 28.11     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\footnotesize
\note Standard errors are clustered at the household level. Significance levels:
%
\item[*] $p<$0.1; \item[**] $p<0.05$; and \item[***] $p<0.01$
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

and gives result, where decimal numbers are aligned at decimal point (regardless if they have minus sign or are in braces) and integer numbers in curly braces grouped if they are longer than three digits:

[image]

**Edit:**

With new version of the `siunitx` package above MWE doesn't work, since it hasn't defined `input-symbols` (and `group-four-digits`) option anymore. So you need to make one of the following changes:

- replace `\usepackage{siunitx}` with `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]` which invoke backward combability to `siunutx` version 2, or
- use the following settings for `S` columns:

```
\sisetup{input-open-uncertainty=,
         input-close-uncertainty=,
    table-align-text-before= false,
    table-format={(}-1.2{$^{***}$}, 
         group-minimum-digits=4}
```

After this changes result is the same as was at original answer.